# how to create multiple index in elasticsearch using fluentd ( td-agent.cong)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4, fluentd

I am setting up EFK Stack. In Kibana I want to represent one index for application and one index for syslogs.

I am using fluentd for log forwarding.

syslogs --> /var/log/messages and /var/log/secure

application --> /var/log/application.log

what is the td-agent.cong to create two index plz help

thanking you

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the ElasticSearch output plugin and want to use kibana you can config your indices names by changing the **logstash_prefix** attribute.

read the documentation : [elasticsearch output plugin documentation](https://github.com/uken/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch#logstash_prefix)

I have added this following fluentd.conf file to demonstrate your usecase. 
In this file I have 2 matches: 
1. **"alert"** - will pipe all logs with "alert" (FluentLogger.getLogger("alert")) to "alert" index in elasticsearch.

2. **default match** - will pipe all logs to elasticsearch with "fluentd" index (which is the default index of this plugin).

   ## fluentd/conf/fluent.conf

   @type forward
     port 24224
     bind 0.0.0.0

   ```
   <match alert.**>
     @type copy
     <store>
       @type elasticsearch
       host elasticsearch
       port 9200
       logstash_format true
       logstash_prefix alert
       logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
       type_name access_log
       tag_key @log_name
       flush_interval 1s
     </store>
     <store>
       @type stdout
     </store>
   </match>


   <match *.**>
     @type copy
     <store>
       @type elasticsearch
       host elasticsearch
       port 9200
       logstash_format true
       logstash_prefix fluentd
       logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
       include_tag_key true
       type_name access_log
       tag_key @log_name
       flush_interval 1s
     </store>
     <store>
       @type stdout
     </store>
   </match>
   ```